Avocado tree leaves turning brown in a week after sun exposure
I am in zone 9b. I bought a Mexicali and Fuerte avocado tree. Both were kept in shade (previous 2 avocado trees died in the summer). To acclimatize the one (Mexicali), I moved it in partial sun. The leaves started turning brown from the edges and moved onwards. Nearly 60% is in that state. I read a blog on avocadobuddy and it appears that I may need to add iron. Any thoughts or suggestions based on experience? If iron is needed, what is a good source?

Please add a Picture.

Please see attached. The plant is now in shade. New leaves are forming, however it appears that they are turning brown as well. New leaves also have a bit of spotted discoloration.

What is your watering pattern.  I'm no expert - and am probably wrong, but to me it looks like one problem is the tree is dying of thirst.  Are you able to immerse the whole root system into a bucket of water for 5 minutes or so (until all the bubbles of air stop coming out - don't leave it in the bucket of water though) and then watch and see if it perks up?

Again, thank you for reviewing this.
I water every other day till I see some coming out of the drain holes. When I stick my finger in soil, it comes out a little wet.
Two notes: a) the leaves turned brown when I moved it in a spot where the plant got direct sun for a few hours. It was fine when it was under the shade. b) I have a another avocado plant which I kept in the shade and it stayed fine
I will try the immersion process and see if it helps.

What are they planted in? It's difficult to see from the photo.
